# How to write some jquery script in drupal 7?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

How can I write a `jquery` script in `drupal-7`?  I need some jquery slidetoggle animation on my working site. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div.toggle_area').find('div.toggle_content').hide().end().find('div.toggle_label').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: i am beginer for drupal-7, i need my working site some jquery slidetoggle animation..i try to write code using html editor in drupal 7,but one time write the code  then save and exit,again doesnot visible the  code in html editor.
where place to make the code in drupal 7????????*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use drupal_add_js function for this.

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
                 jQuery('div.toggle_area').find('div.toggle_content').hide().end().find('div.toggle_label').click(function() {
                   jQuery(this).next().slideToggle(); 
                 });
               });", 'inline');
```

Manual:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

Answer (score 0):

(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {

attach: function(context, settings) {

/*Add your js code here*/

//use comm as a class value since you want to group multiple elements
  $('.ticks').click(function() {

```
//if you want to hide previously opened comment when a new one is clicked
$('.comments').slideToggle("slow");
```

});

```
$('.ticks1').click(function() {


$('.comments1').slideToggle("slow");
```

});

}

};
})(jQuery);